# Going back to previous commit in SourceTree

Tags: git, bitbucket, commit, git-checkout, revert

I am new to Git, and I was trying to revert back to a previous commit in SourceTree. I right clicked on the commit I was going to revert to and then clicked checkout. It gave me a prompt saying that my working copy would become a detached head. What does this mean and is this something I should avoid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I revert back to earlier commit using source tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253914/how-do-i-revert-back-to-earlier-commit-using-source-tree)

Comment: You _could_ revert this commit, but a generally safer course of action would be to make a revert commit to undo this commit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Per Git-Tower's Article : [What's a "detached HEAD" in Git?](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/detached-head-when-checkout-commit)

> **Understanding how "checkout" works**
>
> With the "git checkout" command, you determine which revision of your
>   project you want to work on. Git then places all of that revision's
>   files in your working copy folder.
>
> Normally, you use a branch name to communicate with "git checkout"
>
> ```
> $ git checkout development
> ```
>
> However, you can also provide the SHA1 hash of a specific commit
>   instead:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout 56a4e5c08
> Note: checking out '56a4e5c08'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state...
> ```
>
> This exact state - when a specific commit is checked out instead of a
>   branch - is what's called a **detached HEAD**.
>
> [image]
>
> **The problem with a detached HEAD**
>
> The HEAD pointer in Git determines your current working revision (and
>   thereby the files that are placed in your project's working
>   directory). Normally, when checking out a proper branch name, Git
>   automatically moves the HEAD pointer along when you create a new
>   commit. You are automatically on the newest commit of the chosen
>   branch.
>
> When you instead choose to check out a commit hash, Git won't do this
>   for you. The consequence is that when you make changes and commit
>   them, these changes do NOT belong to any branch. This means they can
>   easily get lost once you check out a different revision or branch: not
>   being recorded in the context of a branch, you lack the possibility to
>   access that state easily (unless you have a brilliant memory and can
>   remember the commit hash of that new commit...).

**Summary :**
From SourceTree, Kindly Checkout to Particular Branch Instead of Checking out to Particular Commit.

Answer (score 2):

**December 9, 2020.**

I am using ***Sourcetree***. If you would like go your previous commit, you can just double click on previous commit. After that, if you want you can create a new branch and merge with your old branch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems not exactly related to git, but specific to the git client / provider you are using ( bitbucket I suspect).

I would suggest you to use the command line client, instead of web UI to learn git better.

In detached head state, whatever changes you make (and commit) gets detached from the commit tree, and you need additional work to put that commit back to the commit tree. Normally we don't make changes in detached head state, it is used for re-arranging the commit tree. But it is worth experimenting in detached state.