# Sourcetree - Pull from specific commit

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, git-commit

i might be asking silly question, but i can't find a clear answer for my question. My case is, i'm trying to pull from certain commit in sourcetree history. What should i do ?.

1. Click the specific commit and use check out ?.
2. User revert commit to specific commit ?.

Because we had problem with the current code, and i want to pull from the last stable code. I already push all my changes. So what i want is just to pull from the specific commit, and then use the code from there for production.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you want to revert your branch to an earlier state.  Is this a permanent need, or would you plan to return to your current point later on?

Comment: I don't have any branch, just one master. I just want to pull from specific commit temporary, just to compile for production.

Comment: Your answer is actually in the question.

Comment: Thank you guys, i found my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253914/how-do-i-revert-back-to-earlier-commit-using-source-tree jumping from @TimBiegeleisen link. So the answer is options 1 in my question.